# Python decorator - Check if user is admin

Tags: python, jwt, flask-restful

I am creating simple API using flask, and I want to check if user which is trying to access is admin. This is function which should decide if user is admin or not

```
def admin_required(f):
    wraps(f)
    @jwt_required()
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        current_user = get_jwt_identity()
        if current_user != "test1":
            return jsonify(admin=False), 200
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function()
```

And this is endpoint

```
@app.route("/am_i_admin", methods= ["GET"])
@jwt_required()
@admin_required
def am_i_admin():
    return jsonify(admin=True), 200
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jozkomrkvicka/PycharmProjects/API/my_api/my_api.py", line 166, in <module>
    def am_i_admin():
  File "/Users/jozkomrkvicka/PycharmProjects/API/my_api/my_api.py", line 92, in admin_required
    return decorated_function()
  File "/Users/jozkomrkvicka/PycharmProjects/API/my_api/my_api.py", line 88, in decorated_function
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
  File "/Users/jozkomrkvicka/PycharmProjects/API/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/utils.py", line 62, in get_jwt_identity
    return get_jwt().get(config.identity_claim_key, None)
  File "/Users/jozkomrkvicka/PycharmProjects/API/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/utils.py", line 26, in get_jwt
    decoded_jwt = g.get("_jwt_extended_jwt", None)
  File "/Users/jozkomrkvicka/PycharmProjects/API/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/Users/jozkomrkvicka/PycharmProjects/API/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

I don't know where is the problem, I did this according [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator) documentation. Could someone help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: try `return decorated_function` instead of `return decorated_function()`, i.e. don't *call* the function

Comment: please fix your code indentation in the question. It is not just a thing to make the code pretty in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the indentation in your post what is actually in your code, because it is indented wrong. Here is an example of an authentication check (not an admin check), but you can see how the indentation should look. You are also missing the decorator on wraps(f).

```
def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Comment: thank you, indetation is correct, I just wrote it wrong here. Decorator was really missing thank you.